# The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a very simple workflow which creates a log, sends an email to a user to preform a task when the item is created then sends a different email to an external address at the same time.  A field is updated using the set field in current item and another log is created.

When I enter the first item in the list the work flow starts but when the second item is created the workflow fails with the following response "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information"

I am using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation and Sharepoint Designer 2010.  I have searched everywhere and even tried inserting 1 minute pause after the first log but it doesn't help.

Comment: Could you please provide more details(field type, value and etc) about set field action?